# What is the difference between contig- and read-based sequence alignment?

Tags: dna-sequencing, sequence-alignment, sequence-assembly

I am trying to understand the difference between read based and contig based alignment. Is contig based alignment refer to de novo assembly and then it is align to a reference genome. I am confused that if you have read based alignment then what is the importance of aligning contigs on the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never heard the term “contig based alignment”, and your question is the only Google hit of this exact query (apart from [a 2012 patent application](https://www.google.com/patents/US8209130)).

That said, and without knowing the exact context, I am assuming that you are essentially right: contig-based alignment probably refers to the *de novo* assembly of reads into contigs, which are then aligned into a scaffold by use of a reference.